# Is there a name for logos with four letters in the quadrants of an X?

Tags: logo, style-identification

I'm trying to do some research into these types of logos but I can't find anything of use on Google using the buzzwords - 'Cross logo', 'X logo', 'X with text around logo'. Is there a certain name for this design?

[image: example logo]

Comment: Extremely relevant: http://www.hipsterlogogenerator.com/

Comment: Am I the only one who reads this as OLGO?

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41269/how-should-i-position-the-letters-in-a-square-logo-to-read-h-s-s-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not really a formal name but you can find it as *Crossed X* logo. Or just *Crossed* logo but that will yield more diverse results, namely including those with religious crosses as well.

The design originally stems from New York Hard Core ([NYHC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_hardcore)), as described in this terrific article [22 Iconic Music Logos Explained](http://www.redbullmusicacademy.com/magazine/iconic-logos)

[image: NYHC Logo]

Nowadays its frequently associated with "hipster branding," as evident by these resources:

- [Crossed “Х” as a Trend. Websites with Hipster Logos](http://blog.templatemonster.com/2014/01/07/websites-with-hipster-logos-showcase/)
- [Crossed "X" Hipster logo on Pinterest](http://www.pinterest.com/dezzig/crossed-x-hipster-logo/)
- [Your Logo Is Not Hardcore](http://yourlogoisnothardcore.tumblr.com/)

Comment: I don't have a handy example, but I'm fairly sure that I have seen such logos used for 100+ year old organizations, and that it's rather unlikely that the design "originally stems" from something as late as the 1980'ies. But maybe I'm mistaken, need to look for examples.

Comment: Of course, Hamburg American Clock Company used similar in the 1980s. But the modern trend comes from the NYHC. Regardless the question was for a way to search for it, the historical background was extra :) @Peteris

Answer (score 0):

The original is from British East India Tea company, circa 1770s

Search "east india tea logo" for examples. Everyone else, including the punks, are copying this.

Answer (score -2):

It's a pig pen cipher used for encryption/decryption. It's on old coins. This is nothing new, and it's not from some NY hXc... They aren't OG.

http://www.newworldtreasures.com/images/pillarswaves.jpg

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/Pigpen_cipher_key.svg

Comment: NY hXc means "New York Hard Core" and refers to another answer, "OG" means "original gangster"

Answer (score -3):

I think the well known railroad crossing sign (R X R) cannot be ignored here. Many places which employ this logotype, as mentioned above, only have letters on the sides. Some also include an enclosing circle.

The RR crossing symbol is something that's in the public consciousness, but people don't probably think of it immediately when they see a logo for a bar or beard wax store or leather goods shop.

The sign dates to the 1920s/1930s. The design was standardized in the Manual on Uniform Traffic Control Devices, (MUTCD) adopted in 1935.

[image: RR-crossing-classic]
[image: RR-crossing-barsonly]

Comment: What does this have to do with the question being asked?

Comment: Hey afwaller, can you explain a little further how this information will help the person who asked the question? I tried searching for "Railroad Crossing Logo" and all I got were railroad signs, not examples of logos using that type of layout. I encourage you to edit your question and improve upon it!